# Interpolation in angular 2 isn't working inside a string from json file

Tags: html, angular, typescript

Am using **'angular-l10n'** language translation in my angular 2 project. I have following string with interpolation which is actually read from a jsonfile for language translatioin

> This will change the ongoing,Recurring scheduled effective {{SunDate}}. Any exception schdeule from {{SunDate}} forward will be overwritten.

to show a message in primeng dialoge box.

The interpolation of angular 2 doesnt works here. How do i make it work?

Comment: That's not supposed to work. Angular-specifics only work when they are added statically to a components template.

Comment: Elaborate your question with your code and json data

Answer (score 0):

Angular interpolation is effective within a template. You must use TypeScript string interpolation using `${}`.

```
let world = 'world';
return `Hello ${world}`; // Hello world
```